# Как расположить такие блоки намного проще?

Tags: html, css

Делал всё это через костыли

За flexbox ничего не знаю, статьи на моём примере ничему не учат, но уверен, что всё это можно расположить также в тысячу раз проще.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<div class="blocks">
        <div class="blck buttons">
                <div class="buttons-1">
                    <h1 class="title">Buttons</h1>
                    <a href="#" class="btn-1">Button 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-2">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-2">Button 2</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blck slider_block">
            <h1 class="title">Slider</h1>
                <div class="sl">
                    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blck textbox_block">
            <h1 class="title">Textbox</h1>
                <div class="tb">
                    <input type="text" size="40" class="textbox">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.buttons-1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.73);
    border: 0.7px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    backdrop-filter: blur(22px);
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    padding: 23px;
    top: 393px;
    left: 42%;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
}

.buttons-2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 485px;
    left: 42%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: rgba(62, 72, 156, 0.21);
    border: 0.4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
    backdrop-filter: blur(18px);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background: rgba(115, 113, 139, 0.089);
    border: 0.4px solid rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.07);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 10px 97px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 5px 13px;
    width: 289px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.slider_block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.73);
    border: 0.7px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    backdrop-filter: blur(22px);
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    padding: 23px;
    top: 610px;
    left: 42%;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
}

.sl {
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.textbox_block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.73);
    border: 0.7px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    backdrop-filter: blur(22px);
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    padding: 23px;
    top: 378px;
    left: calc(50% - 0px/2 + 210px);
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Тут очень все просто вы хоть базу CSS изучали? Стили явно с фигмы подобраны...

Comment: Я стараюсь изучать CSS сразу на практике, так проще запомнить значения свойств и синтаксис.

Answer (score 0):

Проще конечно на grid - смотрите сами

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
  grid-gap: 5vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5vh 10vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url(https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/1400/0868a088493051.5dd7a41b79d6f.jpg);
}

.outer1,
.outer2,
.outer3 {
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.outer1 {
  height: 90%;
}

.outer2,
.outer3 {
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="outer1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="outer2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="outer3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо для дивов прописать `display: flex;` и `flex-direction: row;`, и задать падинги или высоту и длину. И дивы смогут располагаться на одной линии.